# I want to test the part that calls the Para API in Scoold

Tags: para, scoold

When receiving an api call from para, the authentication key seems to change every time. What should I do?

I tried calling the api but it doesn't work. Please tell me how to simulate the part that calls the para api

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Para uses the [AWS v4 Signature](https://paraio.org/docs/#033-restauth) algorithm for API authentication.
The secret key does not change on each request unless you regenerate it first.
Para also supports another method of authentication - JSON Web Tokens (JWT).
The Para documentation contains a section on this topic - "[Creating super tokens](https://paraio.org/docs/#creating-super-tokens)". This way you can issue long-lived tokens which can be used for accessing the API:

```
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOi0._MKAH6SGiKSoqgwmqUaxuMyE
```